# Where to get analytics reporting realtime v3 API KEY?

Tags: oauth, google-analytics, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-api

spend about 4 hours but can not find where to get the key for this GET

```
https://www.googleapis.com/analytics/v3/data/realtime?ids=ga*****&metrics=rt%3AactiveUsers&**key={YOUR_API_KEY}**
```

Have tried different api keys from here https://console.developers.google.com/apis/credentials/key/
but no one is working. 
Always got this result

```
    {  
   "error":{  
      "errors":[  
         {  
            "domain":"global",
            "reason":"required",
            "message":"Login Required",
            "locationType":"header",
            "location":"Authorization"
         }
      ],
      "code":401,
      "message":"Login Required"
   }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

> `Login Required`

Means that you don't have access to do what you are trying to do.

The Google Analytics Real-time API is actually a [private API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/authorization).  This means that the data within is Private user data.  For private user data you need to use an access token to access it.    Only public APIs can be accessed using an API key.

So "Key="  will not work you need to use "access_token=" access token must be a valid authenticated access token. Not the API key from Google Developers console. This is why you are seeing the : `Login Required` error message you need access.

In order to get an access token you must be authorized [Real Time Reporting API - Authorization](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/realtime/v3/authorization)

Note: The Real Time Reporting API, in limited beta, is available for developer preview only. [Sign up](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSc9OpoDGB3tBD7oy1OG9fyum8KBIxs-2ihPCsHp13WTnM-SSQ/viewform) to access the API.

Comment: I would love to know the reason for the -1.  The cause of his problem is he is using an API "key=" with the realtime API and should be using "Access_token=".   Key= will not work with this api.